# How do you integrate a physics integral?

Tags: work, integration, vector-fields, calculus, moment-of-inertia

I've only taken Physics I (w/ calc) in uni, so physics is pretty new to me, and I'm only through Calculus 2.

However, I keep seeing integrals like these everywhere in physics, and want to know how to even start evaluating them. How do I evaluate an integral with an entirely different d than the integrand?

Two (simple but demonstrative) examples: moment of inertia and work:
$$I=\int r^2dm $$
$$W=\int \vec{F}*d\vec{r} $$

How would I even start in evaluating either one of these? I get the point is to evaluate radius squared over a differential mass or force over a differential displacement, but how does that work out in the actual math? If given an exotically-shaped (or even 3d???) disc or cylinder, respectively, how would I go about deriving a moment of inertia equation for that?

Comment: E.g. $r^2dm=r(x,y,z)^2 \rho(x,y,z) dxdydz$ where $\rho$ is the mass density. The other case is $F(x(t),y(t),z(t))\cdot v(t)dt$, i.e. an integral along the trajectory.    Basically, they are conventient short-hand notation: you must know what is their physical meaning in order to write down their expression for the specific problem at hand.

Comment: @hyportnex how would you integrate $\mathrm{d}m$ as a Riemann-Stieltjes integral? Wouldn't it make more sense to say that $m$ is a measure, and say that it's a Lebesgue integral? In particular, that way also works for both discrete and continuous mass distributions.

Comment: In short, you express $m$ as a function of $r$

Comment: @Sandejo you are right and I was talking nonsense, a senior moment; see https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/senior%20moment

Answer (score 1):

These integrals will be a main focus of a typical Calculus III course! (At least for those that I've seen and taught in an American 3-semester calculus sequence)

In particular, multivariable Calculus introduces one to several new conceptualizations of an integral that allow one to integrate over more complicated scenarios than functions like $y = f(x)$. These integrals can all be formulated in a manner similar to Reimann Sums, as the limit of sums as a term in the summation tends towards zero.

The work integral is an example of a [Line Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral)(wikipedia link) over a vector field $\vec{F}$. The $\mathrm{d}\vec{r}$ can be conceptualized as an infinitesimal (or sufficiently small) segment of a path we are moving along, pointing tangent to the path (direction we are moving along the path). We no longer can think of our differential as a scalar, because we are not integrating along a single coordinate axis as we do in Calculus I, we are following a path through three spacial coordinates, so it doesn't make sense to ask about a change in an input variable until we figure out a way to describe our path.

So first, we need to come up with a *parametrization* of our path; this is often denoted by $\vec{r}(t) = \langle x(t), y(t), z(t)\rangle$. As we evaluate this path along $t$ values, its output traces the path one is moving on through the field $\vec{F}$. Plug in a scalar $t$ value, get out a vector describing a point on the path! Although $t$ can be considered time, this is a mathematical definition and independent. (Additionally, work does not depend upon time taken; any parametrization of the same curve will yield the same work).

Once we have a formula for our path, we can define this line integral as:

$$
\int \vec{F}\cdot \mathrm{d} \vec{r} = \int_{t_1}^{t_2}\vec{F}\big(\vec{r}(t)\big)\cdot \vec{r}'(t)\mathrm{d}t
$$

where $t_1$ and $t_2$ correspond with the beginning and end of our path. You may note that this is now a definite integral of a single variable $t$. The operation between the $\vec{F}$ and the tangent vector $\vec{r}'$ is the *dot product*, a specific vector product that returns a scalar. Evaluating it will result in a scalar function that can be integrated using standard methods from Calculus (assuming it's integrable).

The dot product between two vectors will tell us how aligned they are in direction via the formula $\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v} = |\vec{u}||\vec{v}|\cos(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle between the vectors. So by dot producting the $\vec{F}$ field with our tangent vector $\vec{r}'(t)$, we are measuring not only the magnitudes of the field and tangent vector, but also how much they align.

If we pick sufficiently small change in $t$, say $\Delta t$, we can approximate that section of our curve as a straight line. In this case, the dot product of force and distance along the curve, which is given by $\vec{F}\cdot\vec{r}'\Delta t$, will yield the work done along this small linear approximation of the curve. The integral adds up all of these tiny approximations to the line while taking the limit as $\Delta t\to 0$. This integral will then converge to the total amount of work done following the path continuously. If we are in a simple scenario, such as evaluating a constant force along a coordinate axis (let's say along $y$), all of our vectors are one dimensional and can be treated as scalars. This yields the conventional introductory definition of work, force times distance.

$$
\int_{t_1}^{t_2}Fy'(t)dy = F\int_{t_1}^{t_2}y'(t)dy = F\cdot(y2 - y1)
$$

There is a lot more subtlety to these integrals and how they work, several short cuts (work-energy theorem), and many more examples of integrals (surface, volume, flux) that are all addressed in a standard Calculus III curriculum. Returning to your question of "How do I evaluate an integral with an entirely different d than the integrand?", the notations $\mathrm{d}\vec{r}$, $\mathrm{d}m$, $\mathrm{d}S$ etc are not evaluated as in the same manner as a Calc I integral; they all require replacement by some sort of description or parametrization for a line, surface or volume in order to work. Once that occurs however, the result should look a lot more familiar such as above with the line integral! The notations are incredibly convenient short hands however, and depending on your formulation may describe exact differential quantities. At the least, they tell you the type of integral you will need to compute.